# Change command line args (as shown in htop etc) in forked process

Tags: python, fork

I use `os.fork` and do some things in my forked process (but not `os.exec`).
In tools like `htop`, for the forked process it shows the same command line args as the parent process.
I want to change that it shows some custom command line for the forked process.
How?

I saw [this for C](https://www.uofr.net/%7Egreg/processname.html):

```
int argv0size = strlen(argv[0])
strncpy(argv[0],"child-thread-name",argv0size);
```

I'm not really sure whether this always works or whether this is save.
If this works, is there an easy way to do this in Python? Just overwriting `sys.argv` in the forked process would obviously not have the same effect.

Comment: Note that it's only overwriting as much as fits into your program name. As for implementing it in Python -- ctypes is your friend.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So you say this should work in general? But then, how do I get the `argv` pointer in Python, via ctypes or any other way?

Comment: I'd have to read the cpython implementation to figure out where it keeps the original arguments passed to its `main` to answer that -- but if you've already taken a shot at grepping its source, I'd hate to duplicate the work.

Comment: ...if we're lucky, `sys.orig_argv` is wrapping the original C strings, rather than pointers to them, so we just need to do effectively the same unwrapping that any C extension to Python is doing.

Comment: ...grepping cpython, note existence of `Py_GetArgcArgv`

Comment: ...and it does look to me like `_Py_SetArgcArgv` stores the original pointers rather than copies, so they're there to be found.

Comment: ...well, maybe not. Being lists of `wchar_t*`s rather than `char_t*`s is a bit worrying.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! I haven't looked into it yet recently but I think I will figure this out. Unfortunately, I fear that all of this sounds a bit too fragile to really be used in production...?

Comment: `Py_GetArgcArgv` is part of the stable API for use by C extensions to Python, so that part you should be able to trust, at least as far as its documentation has associated guarantees. (OTOH, `orig_argv` vs `argv` was introduced in Python 3.10; I haven't looked at how long the other bits have existed, but it's possible there were other additions at the same time).

Comment: Looking at [frozenmain.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Python/frozenmain.c), I think the original `argv` is never really stored anywhere. It makes copies and only operates on them.

Comment: Are you using freeze to package your program?

Comment: ...otoh, the calls to `Py_DecodeLocale` are consistent with the `wchar_t` vs `char_t` discrepancy, so that indeed may be the case.

Comment: Hmm. You could solve this if you were willing to build your own main that stores the "real" argv before calling into the Python world, to have it available for reference after the fork.

Comment: It was just the first main() I found. I think the real normal entry point is [here, main.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d291a82df33cd8c917a374fef2a2373beda78b77/Modules/main.c). That looks a bit different. However, I was following a bit the code and I'm not sure if the original `argv` is stored.

Comment: The `main.c` you linked is called from [`python.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Programs/python.c), so whether we call `PyConfig_SetBytesArgv` or `PyConfig_SetArgv` depends on our platform. I gather, though, that we're not targeting Windows, so it should always be the `Bytes` version.

Comment: ...so, by my reading, it's [`_PyArgv_AsWstrList`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0ff626f210c69643d0d5afad1e6ec6511272b3ce/Python/preconfig.c#L78) where we're _actually_ discarding our original argv (on non-Windows platforms where argv isn't already multibyte), and storing a multibyte decoding instead.